# Query for Distance Calculation for hotel storelocator not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Here is my Query in Model

```
 $array = array('dealercity' => $citycheck, 'lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng, 'sometype' => $sometypeid, 'type' => $typeid);
     $this->db->select("*, (
  3959 * acos (
  cos ( radians($lat) )
  * cos( radians( lat ) )
  * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) )
  + sin ( radians($lat) )
  * sin( radians( lat ) )
)) AS distance");   

     $this->db->from('tbl_dealer_list');
     $this->db->where($array);
     $this->db->having('distance < 25');                     
     $this->db->order_by('distance');   
     $this->db->limit(25, 0);
     $query = $this->db->get();
```

The Problem is Query is not showing any error. When I searching a particular location the the same exact location is displaying. The nearby locations with in 20 miles is not working. I am Using Codeigniter and Mysql.
Any One Knows the answer Please point out the error.

When I run the query the distance calculated is shows is some value like 0.00005899369716644287. and I'm checked with distance more than this value still not showing the nearby locations and the showing the location when one location is exists more than one in the database.

Comment: Can you give some samples of the lat and lng from your data and the exact values of $lng and $lat?

Comment: Without CI active record, Just post the SQL only

Comment: great!@Abdulla Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $return =array();

       $query= $this->db->query("select *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM tbl_dealer_list WHERE dealertype =  '".$dealerid."'AND vehicletype =  '".$vehicleid."' HAVING distance < 20 ORDER BY distance");

      if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
        return $query->result();//$query->result_array()

         }
```